# Проблемы с бд C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, суть проблемы то что я делаю "Регистрацию" для этого я делаю проверки что бы небыло одинаковых логинов делаю проверку:

```
DB db = new DB();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`, `surname`) VALUES (@login, @pass, @name, @surname)", db.GetConnection());

command.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1;
command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNameField;
command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userSurname;
command.Parameters.Add("@surname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2;

db.openConnection();

if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
  MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт успешно зарегистрирован");
else
  MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт не зарегистрирован");
db.closeConnection();
```

У меня выводит какой-то бред типа

> System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: Admin

Но если я впишу где textBox1 ".Text" У меня будет все работать как надо но не будет работать проверка, что делать?

Comment: Где выводит? Кто выводит? Что и куда вы хотите вписать?

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1;` ?? Вы текстбокс в базу отправляете? Может таки `command.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;` ?

Comment: В этом то и загвоздка то что если я так напишу оно не проверяет тоисть если я введу одинаковый логин оно не проверит и повторно зарегистрирует аккаунт

Comment: в смысле не проверит? Как эта проблема вообще относится к тому факту, что вы вместо текста пытаетесь записать в БД весь текстбокс?

Comment: Ладно, хорошо с этим решили, я просто привел как пример, но факт остается фактом, почему оно не проверяет?

Comment: А должно? В базе на поле `login` создан уникальный ключ?

Comment: Я чуть чуть не понимаю о чем вы

Comment: У вас 2 пути. 1) В таблице `users` столбец `login` присвоить свойство уникальности, и тогда при попытке добавить повторяющийся логин будет вываливаться ошибка. 2) Перед внесением нового логина сначала сделать запрос к БД на предмет существования такого логина и если такого нет, то производить сохранение.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот в этом столбце ставите галочку на Unique Key, MySql проверит является ли данные уникальными, если нет, то выдаст ошибку
Чтобы избежать ошибку просто используете в коде try-catch. Именно эту ошибку ищи тут
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.29.php
Или сначала можно с помощью запроса проверить существует ли такое имя и выводить ошибку в Messagebox, но это слишком трудно и нудно